# Python Unittest: AttributeError: no attribute 'assertTrue' when running on Linux

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing, assert, attributeerror

I am running some very simple unit tests in `Python`, and found that the `assertTrue()` function won't work, while in the same testcase the `assertEqual()` is working fine.
To simplify the issue, I have minimized the code into the following:

```
import unittest

class easyTest (unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This batch of codes runs perfectly on my Windows laptop, but returns

```
AttributeError: easyTest instance has no attribute 'assertTrue'
```

when I try to run it on Linux.

On both laptops, I am using `python 2.7.6`, on IDE `pyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.4`. My Linux laptop is running `Ubuntu 14.04.1`

I have found a very similar question here:
[AttributeError: TestSwitch instance has no attribute 'assertTrue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823574/attributeerror-testswitch-instance-has-no-attribute-asserttrue)
And since it seems that nobody is answering the question, I am asking here again, hoping for some prominent answers.

Comment: Please add a "print unittest" just after the import and check you really get the stdlib's `unittest` module.

Comment: does pycharm shows any error? if you are importing some other unittest (could be the issue) it might throw this error. try opening this TestCase class and check if this function is in there.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and on terminal it gives me the location of unittest.pyc before reporting the Error. and the location of unittest.pyc is in .../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyUnit-1.4.1-py2.7.egg.

Comment: could u add import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() before self.assertTrue and list all aviable self.ass..
and try to execute it by python3

Comment: @LumiWang PyUnit is long deprecated, cf my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, the unittest version you are using is (the long deprecated) stand-alone `PyUnit 1.4.1` package. As the [package's homepage mentions](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/):

> Unless you're stuck in the year 2000, PyUnit is in your Python standard library as module unittest.

And indeed, `unittest` was added to the stdlib in Python 2.1.

IOW, unless you're stuck with an antediluvian legacy code base (using Python < 2.1 !), you should just uninstall PyUnit and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @bruno! I simply removed the whole package and now it works fine. It's a work laptop with some history, I hope my other codes are still working without this. Many thanks!

Comment: Unless your system Python is < 2.1you should be ok. Note that `virtualenv` is a great tool to avoid issues with differing dependencies across projects...

Comment: yes it seems everything's working fine by far! I'm working on some company project currently. I have heard about the virtualev for some time and will use it in new projects! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have a second unittest module or package in your python path?

If you created a unittest.py file or a unittest directory containing an `__init__.py` file, python could find that before it finds the normal module in the standard python library.

Naming a local module or package unittest is the equivalent of naming a local variable list or dict or map; you are masking the built-in name with a local redefinition.

Rename that module or package to something else to fix this.

Comment: wouldn't that throw the error when he tried to define a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`? (genuinely asking, I wouldn't be sure one way or the other)

Comment: Thanks Karim, I ran a "find usages" in PyCharm and the only unittest.py I got is the one protected in the lib. So I guess it's not the problem here.

Comment: As Bruno found out, it seems that there is indeed an ancient PyUnit package installed on the unix machine. I don't know why I didn't find the other package while searching for usages in pyCharm though.